# Problems installing cocos3d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I am attempting to install cocos3d and during the installation I must locate all the files from when I installed cocos2d.  I could not for the life of me find where these were so I just re downloaded it and re installed it and used those files when attempting to instal cocos3d, however it spit all these errors back at me

```
cocos3d installer

Copying cocos2d libraries to workspace
...copying cocos2d files
...copying cocos2d dependency files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Torgerson/cocos2d/external/FontLabel" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...copying CocosDenshion files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Torgerson/cocos2d/CocosDenshion/CocosDenshion" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...copying cocoslive files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Torgerson/cocos2d/cocoslive" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...copying cocoslive dependency files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Torgerson/cocos2d/external/TouchJSON" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
done!

Installing Xcode 4 cocos3d iOS template
----------------------------------------------------

...removing old template: /Users/Torgerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d Application.xctemplate
...creating destination directory: /Users/Torgerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d Application.xctemplate
...copying cocos3d Application template files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Torgerson/Templates/Xcode4/cocos3d Application.xctemplate/." failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...creating destination directory: /Users/Torgerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d Application.xctemplate/Resources
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Torgerson/Demos/Common/Resources/hello-world.pod" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...removing old template: /Users/Torgerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d-base.xctemplate
...creating destination directory: /Users/Torgerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d-base.xctemplate
...copying cocos3d-base template files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Torgerson/Templates/Xcode4/cocos3d-base.xctemplate/." failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...removing old template: /Users/Torgerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d-lib.xctemplate
...creating destination directory: /Users/Torgerson/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos3d/cocos3d-lib.xctemplate
...copying cocos3d-lib template files
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Torgerson/Templates/Xcode4/cocos3d-lib.xctemplate/." failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
...copying cocos3d files to cocos3d-lib template
rsync: link_stat "/Users/Torgerson/cocos3d" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
done!
```

And as of now I can not create a new cocos3d project, it all ran but I have no cocos3d template in xcode ?? any help :) thanks

Comment: Install Kobold2D v1.0.5 and get going: http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/Kobold2D+Download

Answer (score 1):

The script apparently tries to copy the files from

```
/Users/Torgerson/cocos2d
```

and

```
/Users/Torgerson/cocos3d
```

Moving cocos2d and cocos3d to these directories should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to problem in installation. Follow the correct installation steps. I also suffered the same problem. So just go through the steps in the following link,

http://www.techipost.com/2011/02/20/installing-cocos3d-for-iphoneipad/

You can check, whether u have installed cocos3d templates or not, using terminal window.